# AWS Lambda with aws-sdk-go-v2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-go

I migrated aws-sdk-go-v2 to v0.31.0 from v0.25.0.

My code is a bit of a Frankenstein's Monster and I want to fully migrate to this version but I can't find the current location/approach for some features.

Specifically:

I had:

```
func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, event events.APIGatewayV2HTTPRequest) (string, error) {}
```

The relevant import was "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events". I had a rake around various service but can't locate an update, is that still correct?

Also func main() used to be:

```
func main() {
lambda.Start(HandleRequest)}
```

But no more Start() method, so what is the correct paradigm now ?

The sdk is a lot better, but I am missing the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you importing both github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda and github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/lambda? If so, try importing the former with:

runtime "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"

And then call runtime.Start(HandleRequest)

As for handling events, see the samples in https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/tree/master/events.

Comment: Thanks. Will give that a go. Seemed odd that we have a lambda package as per github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/lambda and as well as github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda ?

Comment: @Chanonry the `aws-sdk-go-v2` is for interacting with the AWS API - More useful when working against AWS objects